# C++ AVR append to const char *

Tags: c#, c++, string, avr, atmel

In C# you'd have a string, to append to the string I'll do the following:

```
//C#
string str="";
str += "Hello";
str += " world!"
//So str is now 'Hello world!'
```

But in C++ for AVR I use a `const char *`. How could I append to it?

```
const char * str="";
str += "Hello world!"; //This doesn't work, I get some weird data.
str = str + "Hello world!"; //This doesn't work either
```

NOTE: I'm working in Atmel Studio 6 programming an avr so I think the functionality used in C++ by most people is unavailable to use because I get build failures as soon as I try some examples I've seen online. I don't have the `String` data type either.

Comment: You don't have `std::string` available? (`#include <string>`)

Comment: Nope, I have a `string.h` included, allowing me to use `strlen()` etc. but no string type. But appending to `const char *` is ok if I can learn to do it.

Comment: Well you'll have to build your own, or use the plain C "string" handling functions (strcat and the like), and manage the memory yourself. There's about 15.3 quazillion examples of string concatenation in C available on the webs, should be easy to locate.

Comment: :( Is there no simple way to append to `const char *`?

Comment: If by simple you mean "using += and without using `std::string`", then no.

Answer (score 3):

you really should dig into some C Tutorial or book and read the chapter about strings.

`const char * str="";` creates a pointer to an empty string in the (constant) data segment.

`str += "Hello world!"`:

1. string processing dos not work like this in C
2. the memory the pointer points to is constant you should not be able to modify it
3. adding something to a pointer will change the location the pointer points to (and not the data)

since you are on an AVR you should avoid dynamic memory.
defining an empty string constant does not make sense.

little example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 100
char someBuf[MAX_LEN] = ""; // create buffer of length 100 preinitilized with empty string

const char c_helloWorld[] = "Hello world!"; // defining string constant

strcat(someBuf, c_helloWorld); // this adds content of c_helloWorld at the end of somebuf
strcat(someBuf, c_helloWorld); // this adds content of c_helloWorld at the end of somebuf

// someBuf now contains "Hello world!Hello world!"
```

Additional excurse/explanation:
since the avr has harvard arcitecture it cannot (at least not without circumstances) read the program memory. So if you use string literals (like "Hello world!") they require doubled space by default. one instance of them is in the flash memory and in startup code they will be copied to SRAM. depending of your AVR this may matter! you can work around this and only store them in program memory by declaring Pointer using PROGMEM attribute (or something similar) but now you need to explicitly read them from flash at runtime by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, strings in C# are immutable, so the line

```
str += " world!"
```

actually creates a *new* string whose value is that of the original string, with `" world"` appended, and then makes `str` refer to that new string. There are no longer any references to the old string, so it gets garbage collected eventually.

But C-style strings are mutable, and are meant to be modified in place unless you explicitly copy them. So in fact if you have a `const char*`, you cannot modify the string at all, since `const T*` means the `T` data pointed to by the pointer can't be modified. Instead, you have to make a new string,

```
// In C, omit the static_cast<char*>; this is only necessary in C++.
char* new_str = static_cast<char*>(malloc(strlen(str)
                                          + strlen("Hello world!")
                                          + 1));
strcpy(new_str, str);
strcat(new_str, "Hello world!");
str = new_str;
// remember to free(str) at some point!
```

This is cumbersome and not very expressive, so if you are using C++ the obvious solution is to use `std::string` instead. Unlike the C# string, the C++ string has value semantics and is not immutable, but it can be appended to in a straightforward fashion, unlike the C string:

```
std::string str = "";
str += "Hello world!";
```

Again, if you mark the original string `const`, you won't be able to append to it without creating a new string.